# Need to traverse through .cs files in a solution and determine if a function is used

Tags: c#

I am looking to write a utility for work where I can take a list of generated function names (we use a custom-code generation process) and traverse through all of the .cs files within a particular solution and determine if the function is being used. The most difficult thing preventing me from figuring this out is determining whether or not the function is within a commented line or block of code. I planned on just looping through each .cs file and using a streamreader looking for a match on the function name. Is that a good approach to start with?

NOTE: This is a utility that I am looking to write that I can use with various solution files. We have thousands of generated functions from our code-gen utility and I am looking to report on the unused functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would compile the code and use a tool like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) on it, no reason to reinvent the wheel.

This process can be very well automated using a CQL (Code Query Language) statement.

Comment: I am hoping to find a free solution to this because I do not have a NDepend license. If worse comes to worse I may have to purchase one though. +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Depends on how often you need to do that, but you can manually get such a list from reflector - or built a custom reflection tool that generates this report based on your compiled assembly.

Comment: Ahh I think we are on the right path. The generated code ends up in its own assembly. I could store off a list of all the generated function names from the assembly and then load all of the other assemblies in the solution and see what generated functions are called. I just dont know how to tell if an external function call is made via reflection...

Answer (score 1):

I've always gone to:

Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files.

Then a window pops up. You select "Entire Solution" from the 'Look In' drop-down. And then type what you're looking for in the "Find What" field.

EDIT: Oh, I see that you're looking for a *list* of functions. My apologies. I guess this only works for single items...

Comment: I am looking to automate this process by writing a utility that can be used across multiple solutions and report the non-used functions.

Answer (score 1):

The csproj file is xml, so you can use that to get a list of files listed in your projects.  You can single out your method names by looking for code outside of braces within a class, then parsing out any modifiers, return types and arguments, then search each file for all the method names found.  Bonus for stripping comments out of the file before processing.

I am doing something very similar with C code currently, and its worked out alright.

One thing I've done to find function calls (I have a list of calls where I care if they are called in a file) is as follows:

1. Run a regex for the function name on a file that has been stripped of all comments
2. If the regex finds a match, check the file line by line (I report what line a function call was found on)

Comment: How do you strip off all comments?

Comment: I have a regex that searches for // comments, then /* */ comments, there are corner cases you have to watch out for, like when someone uses comments like //*/ to us as a switch between blocks of code.  The better solution would to be to use a parser instead of the large amounts of regex I do, but it was how I originally did it an d havent had a chance to rewrite it